# how to close this background process?

Tags: ubuntu, background-process

How do I close a process when I ran it with

`sudo bash -c 'apt-get -y install texlive-full >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown'` ?

Have no way to track the process in Ubuntu that I'm aware of.

Comment: `sudo pkill apt-get` would be close, if there were no other users running apt-get.  Are you in the same terminal as the original command?

Comment: Yes -- is there also a way to at least track the process?

Comment: You should have gotten a pid as output; are you asking if there’s a way to find it without knowing the pid?

Comment: yes -- never got a pid here.

Comment: It doesn't show on the list if you run `ps -A`? If not, then how do you know it is running?

Comment: Ok found it using `ps -A`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use `ps -A` to list all of the running processes on your system; find the pid of the process in question and then issue `sudo kill [pid]` to close it.

If it's really persistent, use `sudo kill -9 [pid]`.